# wired headphones plugged in and out

Tags: android, audio, headphones

I need an event executing when user plugs in/out wired headphones, it made in HTC sense player.

android.media.AudioManager doesn't generate an event, it even doesn't return a correct value with isWiredHeadsetOn()

How can I know if wired headset plugged or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG).

Comment: @Spin7ion: Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen on broadcast `Intents` with that action.